# To print the power of the number in c using cygwin terminal

Tags: c, cygwin, type-conversion

I am unable to find the exact solution of 2 raise to the power 32 in the following program. I am using cygwin terminal.

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
  int base, expo;

  long long value = 1;
  printf("Enter base number and exponent respectively");
  scanf("%d%d", &base, &expo);

  while (expo != 0)
  {
    value *= base;
    --expo;
  }
  printf("Answer = %ll ", value);

  return 0;
}
```

I would want some help in knowing what datatype would be appropriate for storing the value of 2 raise to 32.

Comment: You are missing a `d` or `i` after `%ll`, `ll` is only the length specifier, the type is still needed.

Comment: OT: It's `int main(void)` at least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`2`<sup>`32`</sup> is equal to `4294967296`. This can be easily resented by `long long` type. Use `%lld` specifier.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the GMP library https://gmplib.org/ (it's designed to work both with C and C++ compilers). With this library you can work with arbitrarily large numbers (maximum is limited only by the computer's memory and the hardware architecture).

Edit: If you expect the `base` and `expo` to yield something that fits into the `long long` type then the other answers offer help. But since your code snippet didn't have validation on the `base` and `expo` I thought you might be interested in representing even larger numbers.